# Can't install windows after adding another stick of ram

Tags: windows-10, boot, memory

So, I have a MSI Bazooka MAX(wifi) MB and a 32gb 3600mhz cl18 2x16 kit of  g.skill trident z rgb memory. When I got the last of my computer components, I didn't put in the second stick of ram in its slot correctly, after doing this i installed ubuntu, and tested out my new computer for a few minutes, then I realized I only had 16gb of ram and not 32, I reseated my ram, and in the bios, it was picking up the 32gbs fine, but ubuntu kept bugging and crashing every time I opened up more than too tabs in Brave Browser, I kept getting a memory error. I eventually gave up and tried to install windows, around 6 times... I got a 16gb USB stick with the correct formatting, get the setup from Microsoft, and ran the installation. After it finishes installing. My computer turns off and on a few times, then gives a error, its different each time, so I can give the specific one. When I gave up on windows, I decided to install PopOS a distro of Linux based on ubuntu, and currently, its working completely fine and I've had no problems so far. There are still a lot of programs I need that are windows only though, so if you have any idea what's going on and/or why its happening, I would really appreciate your advice. Thanks!

```
Full PC Specs:
CPU: Ryzen 5 3400g
MB:  MSI Bazooka b450 max(WIFI)
RAM: G.Skill TridentZ RGB 3600mhz cl18 2x16gb
GPU: N/A
PSU: EVGA b5 80+ bronze 650w psu
```

Comment: you may wish to check your ram for problems. https://www.memtest86.com/

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the machine. Take out (if not already out) the second memory module. Put it on a piece of paper and mark it 2. Take out the first memory module. Put it on a piece of paper and mark it 1. Put the second module in the first slot and start up the computer. Does it start?

If not, the improper insertion damaged the module.

If it does start, turn off and put the first module in the second slot and see if it starts.

This is how to determine what is going on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both modules work since the computer is working completely fine with PopOS and I've run some memory intensive code that uses up to 23gb of ram and still had no problems.

Comment: Look at the memory setup in Windows Device Manager. Also run the manufacturer's Windows Diagnostic App.

Comment: I can't even get into windows, I can make it as far as booting from a USB stick selecting the version on windows I want to install, and pressing the install button, after that finished my system reboots and keeps crashing, This computer is brand new and I just built it. So.... I dont know what the problem is

Comment: Try getting into Safe Mode (with Networking) and repair it from there. Next would be a Startup Repair with the Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: How do I get into safe mode, through the bios?

Comment: Try restarting and then repeated presses of F8.  That normally does it.